# dojo tabContainer title(label)

Tags: dojo, title, tabcontainer

all I have a tabContainer with tiltes(Label) and what I need to achieve is when a tabbed is clicked I want the color to be changed to red or whatever meaning is active and the remaining unactive tab stay maybe black the default color. I have tried searching on the web and the only solution I see is css with class .tabLabel{color: Red;} which changes all the tab title to red also tried the onShow event of which can respond alert event but not the stylesheet. Also if you have the id in the tabcontainer and apply css with dojo javascript it changes the content in the tab not the title. Here a sample code I got fromm dojo to show what I want to achieve.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../_static/js/dojo/../dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">

<script>dojoConfig = {parseOnLoad: true}</script><script src='../../_static/js/dojo/dojo.js'></script><script>require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"]);</script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div style="width: 350px; height: 300px">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My first tab" data-dojo-props="selected:true">
            Lorem ipsum and all around...
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My second tab">
            Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="My last tab" data-dojo-props="closable:true">
            Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

From the above code I want to make title="My first tab" active with a different color of the text and other tabs at default color and when My second tab is clicked make it active and do the same action as the first kind of menu links on a website.
Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can change text color of the active tab by adding this class.

```
.dijitChecked.dijitTab .tabLabel {
    color:red;
}
```

[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/oamiamgod/SepCb/4/)

Comment: Thanks also I did it by putting the content of the title in a span then apply the id within the span I was able to use onShow event to add the css class.